# Is this an example of Undistributed Middle?

Tags: logic, fallacies, syllogism

Is this an example of Undistributed Middle?

> John is not a teenager, since all teenagers are impulsive, and John is not impulsive.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not.

It is a valid argument :

The premise :

> All teenagers are impulsive

is equivalent to :

> for every x, if x is not impulsive, then x is not a teenager.

Thus, using the second premise :

> John is not impulsive

we can correctly conclude with :

> > John is not a teenager.

Comment: Excellent response, Mauro

Answer (score 2):

> John is not a teenager, since all teenagers are impulsive, and John is
>   not impulsive.

1. All teenagers are impulsive people.
2. John is not an impulsive person.
3. Thus: John is not a teenager.

The form is AEE in the second figure (All P are M; No S are M; thus No S are P). The syllogism is valid.

The middle term (impulsive people) is distributed in the minor premise (2).